# download a list of links with reptitive names with wget

Tags: download, wget

I have a list of links, but there are links with different files with the same name. Here is a snippet of my `to_download.txt` file:

```
https://www.url.domain/world/2000/may/15/one
https://www.url.domain/world/2000/nov/07/two
https://www.url.domain/world/2000/nov/17/three
https://www.url.domain/world/2000/apr/17/two
https://www.url.domain/world/2000/feb/13/one
https://www.url.domain/world/2000/jun/26/three
https://www.url.domain/world/2000/apr/25/one
```

When I use `wget -i /to_download.txt` there is only one file for the URLs with repetitive file names (one `one`, one `two`, one `three`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did finally. Suppose all links are in a list named `l`:

```
for url in l:
    n = url.split('/')
    name = n[-1] + '_' + n[-2] + '_' + n[-3] + '_' + n[-4]
    os.system('wget ' + url + ' -O ' + name)
```

I don't think it is the best solution, but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are overwriting the files. You can't have two files with the same name. You can create separate folder for each month or whatever is the pattern.

Comment: But the question is: is there any way to avoid this without creating a different directory for each? I find this answer (https://askubuntu.com/questions/584039/download-files-with-wget-from-a-list-but-save-with-a-specific-naming-pattern), but it is not helpful, since I need to check to see which one of the links I downloaded already to update the `to_download.txt` file.